# how to get Wikipedia's event(portal events) data using wikipedia api in .net?

Tags: api, events, wikipedia

I have to get events from Wikipedia. suppose I type Brazilian Grand Prix, output should not be what Brazilian Grand Prix is but it should be where it is being held in upcoming days/weeks.I have to implement it on asp.net web application. User input should be only event name and he will get output in xml/json format. Please tell me if anyone know how to do this?

we can see all events here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events

But I don't know how to get it programmatically.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what kind of information are you expecting to get? Is it even present at the Wikipedia page in question?

Comment: @Svick: I don't know whether Wikipedia contains any such information or not. If there is any such information, I want to access that.

Comment: @Svick: If I type Sebastian Vettel, Then events related to Sebastian Vettel which are on Wikipedia will come to me. Events means list of events in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure, but it seems to me that you want to get a list of pages whose names are in the form [Portal:Current events/2012 November 25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aCurrent_events/2012_November_25), depending on what exactly do you consider “current”. Then search the code for each of those pages for what you want. If you get a match, output the line that matched.

Probably the easiest way to get the code of a page is to use [`action=raw`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#Raw). Another option is to use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).